# Protractor click on link inside nested repeater and div

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat, protractor

I'm trying to click on "Enter Email" link which in inside nested div and also tr and td have same repeater. Below is sample markup:

```
<div class="table-responsive >
    <table id="vertical-view" class="main-table" ng-table="main-ng-table" >
        <tbody ng-repeat="tbody-ng-repeat" > 

            <tr ng-repeat="main-row-ng-repeat-data">
                <td ng-repeat="main-col-ng-repeat-data" > 
                    <span class="main-span-title">UserName</span>
                </td>
                <td ng-repeat="main-col-ng-repeat-data" > 
                    <div class="item-outer-wrapper>
                        <div class="item-inner-wrapper>
                            <a href="" id="deal" class="editable editable-click ng-binding">Enter UserName</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr ng-repeat="main-row-ng-repeat-data">
                <td ng-repeat="main-col-ng-repeat-data" > 
                    <span class="main-span-title">Email</span>
                </td>
                <td ng-repeat="main-col-ng-repeat-data" > 
                    <div class="item-outer-wrapper>
                        <div class="item-inner-wrapper>
                        <a href="" id="deal" class="editable editable-click ng-binding">Enter Email</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr ng-repeat="main-row-ng-repeat-data">
            </tr>

            <tr ng-repeat="main-row-ng-repeat-data">
            </tr>
        </tbody>

        <tbody ng-repeat="tbody-ng-repeat" > 

        </tbody>

        <tbody ng-repeat="tbody-ng-repeat" > 

        </tbody>

    </table>
</div>
```

the code that i'm using to access the link element and click on Enter Email is look like this

```
var text = element(by.repeater('tbody-ng-repeat').row(0)).all(by.repeater('main-row-ng-repeat-data').row(1)).all(by.repeater('main-col-ng-repeat-data').row(1)).all(by.linkText('Enter Email'));

text.click();
```

Somehow it not clicking on right link. Is there a way to correctly locate link in nested repeater?

Also I'm getting warning on clicking the link

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```